# The debug session type "node" is not supported

Tags: google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I met this error when I want to debug my node.js program in Google Cloud Shell Editor.

Yesterday was OK, it is just happened today. Anyone know what's wrong?

Here is my Launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${file}"
    }
  ]
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVNQH.png)

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed automatically. Maybe Google is updating something.